# What is the difference between these two ways of allocating memory in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am confused about the proper means of allocating memory in Objective-C.  Suppose I have an NSMutableDictionary.  There are two ways I can initialize it:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *alpha = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

or

```
   NSMutableDictionary *alpha = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

What is the difference between them?  I know the first allocates memory for alpha, but what about the second?

Which of these is recommended as the best practice for allocating memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

is exactly the same thing as:

```
[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

It just saves you some typing. It doesn't matter which one you use, as long as you know the difference between a retained object and an autoreleased one. If you're using ARC, then you don't even need to know that.

The convention is:

1. If you see **init**, **new** or **copy**: it's a retained object.
2. If the method name starts with the class name (sans the framework prefix), it's an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 2):

`[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` is a class method on the `NSMutableDictionary` class. It contains the calls to `alloc` and `init`, just as you would do them manually. Due to this being a very commonly used class, its author included this so called "factory method" to make life easier for users of his/her class.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern for more details on this pattern.

As for which is good practice, IMHO you should use the factory method. It makes your own code more readable and saves you typing. Moreover - although I am not sure if this is the case with `NSMutableDictionary` - using the factory method makes maintenance easier for both its developers and yourself, because they are e. g. free to change the concrete subclass implementation you will receive from the factory, without having you change your application code.

As correctly pointed out it the comments, factory methods like this return autoreleased instances of objects, so if you only use them locally in a method, there is no need to worry about them from a memory management point of view. For more details on memory management, autorelease and the new ARC runtime with automatic reference counting, you should deep dive into Apple's documentation on the topic, if you haven't already.

Comment: You have missed the crucial distinction between the two, that `dictionary` returns an autoreleased object and `alloc/init` does not.

Comment: Oh, very good point. Was already in "ARC thinking". I will add that.

Comment: @daniel so you mean to say both are same.except from the autorelease thing.

Comment: Most probably they are the same, but for the autorelease. However, the beauty of this is that you need not care. In the future Apple might change the implementation of the factory method to return a different, more efficient implementations, for example based on what hardware your app is currently running on. This is all hidden behind the scenes.

Comment: @DanielSchneller As you are saying that it is good to use factory method but suppose i am using the factory method everywhere,so will it cause any problem? As i have heard that too much autorelease should be avoided.

Comment: Generally™ it will not cause any problems for 99.9% of use cases. Only in very special cases, e. g. tight loops with many iterations that create a new autoreleased instance in every iteration, *might* become problematic. However I strongly recommend you either a) dig into the iOS/ObjC memory model documentation if you really want to know everything before you go on, or b) don't worry about it, use the factory method (as is generally recommended by Apple, too) and stop worrying about it, until maybe(!) some time in the future you will find a specific problem case where it would not be advised.

Answer (score 1):

Both line will allocate memory for alpha, difference is that second alpha is autorelease object.