# NSSet *someSet = [NSSet alloc] init] vs. NSSet *someSet = [NSSet set]

Tags: iphone, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these two ways of allocating memory in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211075/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-allocating-memory-in-objective)

I got tripped up on this. I realized I don't understand the concept of when I **must** use alloc init to create space for an object on the heap.

Via NSSet's class reference I found the class method "set" (http://goo.gl/ndHjK).

Its description reads "Creates and returns an empty set.", which sounds like precisely what I want. So does this "set" method implicitly perform an alloc init for me?

Or am I confusing two very different things completely?

Comment: God I love stackoverflow. Thanks so much for all your responses! Every single one reinforced the main answer. Thank you!

And I'm actually creating an NSMUtableSet to which I add objects in a for-in loop, from an array. So this question became relevant when it became time to actually create an NSMutableSet object before the for-in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSSet set]`is called a convenience constructor. It returns an autoreleased object, meaning you don't have to care about memory management for that object, unless you retain it explicitly of course.

If you allocate it explicitly, you must also release it.

A convenience constructor looks usually like this:

```
+ ( NSSet *)set
{
    return [ [ [ NSSet alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
}
```

Comment: Unless you're using ARC, you *do* have to care about memory management for every object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `[NSSet set]` is equal to `[[NSSet alloc] init] autorelease]`.

Answer (score 0):

[NSSet set] creates a set via alloc/init/autorelease. It's a naming convention that's commonly practiced in Cocoa. You should call retain on the returned set if you want to use it outside of the scope of the current method.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do with an empty list?  Usually the empty set methods are only used by `NSMutableSet`.

Anyway, you should use `[[NSSet alloc] init]` when you want to control its memory, `[NSSet set]` returns an `autorelease`d set, so you're not responsible for it; anything you `alloc` you are responsible for.