# necessary to initialize NSSet?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, initialization, set, null

They changed some things with Xcode 4, so I was wondering if I needed to initialize an NSSet by

```
NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [NSMutableSet set];
```

or is

```
NSMutableSet *variablesUsed;
```

sufficient? Or does the second option initialize to nil? Is that the same as empty set?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just use `NSMutableSet *variablesUsed;` then you will get a pointer which is set to `nil` and therefore will not be pointing to any kind of set.  `nil` means that it is set to nothing, and is not the same thing as an empty set.  You will get no functionality out of `nil` so you will then need to set variablesUsed to some "real" set in order to make much use of it.

When you use `NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [NSMutableSet set];` or `NSMutableSet *variablesUsed = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];` you are setting the pointer to a brand new, empty set which has been initialized and is ready to use.

Comment: Is there a difference between setting it to [NSMutableSet set] and [[NSMutableSet alloc] init]? Or do they do exactly the same thing?

Comment: To elaborate, if you are using ARC then it is the same thing.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8211075/937822 for details if you aren't using ARC.

Comment: [NSMutableSet set] is autorelease object and [[NSMutableSet alloc] init] retained object(you must release this).

Comment: Yup, that's why I said they are the same thing when using ARC.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The latter, in the latest versions of the runtime, will be initialized to nil. In older versions the result is undefined and it is usually a best practice to assign it to nil or give it an object to point to.

In your case, you'll want to initialize it before you start using it.